# Remover Fundo da CheckBox Wpf Material Design

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Pessoal estou tentando deixar a CheckBox apenas com a marca do quadrado e traço que diz que está marcada.

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
<CheckBox Content="Teste">
     <CheckBox.Resources>
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MaterialDesignCheckBoxOff" Color="White"/>
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
     </CheckBox.Resources>
</CheckBox>
```

Porém quando selecionado o quadrado da checkbox desaparece.

Imagem da Forma que quero deixar a CheckBox

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fazer isso pelo próprio Material Design não vai dar devido a construção do componente em si. Se quiser que eu explico como funciona esse componente no Material Design.

Eu fiz um style baseado na biblioteca do material que deixa como você deseja.

Para modificar a cor do quando **"IsChecked=False"** é só fazer como você já faz com o **"MaterialDesignCheckBoxOff"**, para modificar a cor com o **"IsCheked=True"** é só setar o **"Background"** para a cor desejada

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:wpf="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes">

    <Style x:Key="CustomCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FrameworkElement}}, Path=(TextElement.Foreground)}"/>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MaterialDesignValidationErrorTemplate}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="Click">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractionEllipse">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="48"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractionEllipse">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="48"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractionEllipse">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-24"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractionEllipse">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-24"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="InteractionEllipse">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.3"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Viewbox Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(wpf:CheckBoxAssist.CheckBoxSize)}"
                                 Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(wpf:CheckBoxAssist.CheckBoxSize)}"
                                 VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                 FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                            <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                                <Path x:Name="Graphic"
                                      Data="M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3M19,5V19H5V5H19Z" 
                                      Fill="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignCheckBoxOff}" />
                                <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="M1.750603,3.547478 L4.1236576,5.8087582 10.392243,-0.095367888 11.855669,1.3060774 4.1236576,8.4991511 0.25705349,5.0076278 z" 
                                      Fill="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignCheckBoxOff}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="8" Margin="6,8,0,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12"
                                      Opacity="0"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="InteractionEllipse" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Width="0" Height="0" Canvas.Top="12" Canvas.Left="12" Opacity="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                                         IsHitTestVisible="False">
                                    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform/>
                                            <SkewTransform/>
                                            <RotateTransform/>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsPressed}" Value="true" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(wpf:RippleAssist.IsDisabled)}" Value="false" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Click}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,2,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Graphic"  Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph"    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Glyph" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Graphic" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignCheckBoxDisabled}" />
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.56"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="Graphic" Value="M6,13L6,11L18,11L18,13M19,3H5C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5C21,3.89 20.1,3 19,3Z" />
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Graphic" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Graphic" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignValidationErrorBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignValidationErrorBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```